# Javascript: Get X and Y coordinates/position of cursor in textarea

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have one `text-area` where I am going to give below functionality.

When user type `@` at any cursor point in `text-area` it should open popup to select any field from popup field list. Please refer below image for clear idea. I have used **keyUp event** to achieve this functionality.

[image]

**Issue:** I am able to open popup and close as per requirement but **not able to get specific position**, where it should be open like in above image, means it should be open at same x coordinate where user type `@`. I am able to get those **X and Y coordinate** on mouse events but not able to get those coordinates while user type in `text-area`.

I have implemented above functionality in Vue.Js and below is basic code. Solution in javascript is accepted as this is part of frontend code.

**HTML:**

```
<v-text-field id='myText' label="Insurer" v-on:keyup="onTextChange($event)" v-model="editText" multi-line></v-text-field>
```

**Event:**

```
onTextChange(event) { 
// In event object there is no such clientX/pageX like properties which available in mouse click event
}
```